# Subversion gateway to renumber revisions?

Tags: svn

One of my projects is in a subversion repository (let's call it svn://oldserver/) that will be bald merged into a new repository (Let's say svn://newserver/).

This project makes intensive use of svn:externals to link the source code of some libraries. All externals include a revision number, so that I can currently check out an old version of the code including the libraries.

"oldserver" will be dumped and imported into "newserver". The externals will then be changed to point on the new server, but this works only for the HEAD revision. Two problems for the old revisions:

- The import will shift all the revisions, but not the corresponding numbers in the svn:externals.
- The import will also preserve the original repository name (svn://oldserver/) instead of using the new one.

I wondering if there is such a thing like a gateway server for subversion, which I could run under the name svn://oldserver/ and which would simply get the data from svn://newserver but after renumbering the revision numbers. Does anyone know such a thing?

*Alternative 1: Renumbering the externals with a tool like [svndumptool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) before importing the "oldserver" into the "newserver". But if I make a mistake, I won't be able to correct it afterwards. That's why I rejected this solution.*

*Alternative 2: Let the old server running, simply configured as read-only. It just takes more place on the server hard disks, but I might use this solution if I don't find a better one.*

Answer (score 2):

The safest approach would be to run some sort of script to create tags in the old repository for the specific versions targetted by each external, then point the actual external definition at the HEAD revision of that tag, e.g. given an external definition of

```
-r1234 svn://oldserver/libraries/lib1 lib1
```

make a tag like

```
svn cp -r 1234 svn://oldserver/libraries/lib1 svn://oldserver/libraries/tags/lib1-r1234
```

and change the external

```
svn://oldserver/libraries/tags/lib1-r1234 lib1
```

These tags will then be stable and point to the corresponding revisions in the new repository after the dump and import, and you can just switch them over wholesale from `oldserver` to `newserver`.

Comment: Interesting idea to avoid the problem in the future ! And you are also right, that it would a safer way than my "alternative 1". But I would still need to modify the dump before importing it to the new server.